# 'ng g c' not working (Angular+NativeScript)

Tags: angular, nativescript

When i try to execute ng g c files/file on terminal inside my project this error occurs:

[image]

Comment: Please refer [this thread on github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7630)

Answer (score 0):

The `@nativescript/schematics` package tries to require a utility function from `@schematics/angular`. `@schematics/angular` is a dependency of `@angular/cli`. To fix the error, install the Angular CLI in your project:

```sh
npm install -D @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

npm install

ng g c component-name
```

And make sure you have an environment set for angular like node and variable setup for the ng command.